# Get all words between two delimiters with regex

Tags: regex

I'm tring go get all words betwenn two delimiters.

Example:

> |Test1|Test2|Test3|

```
\|(.*?)\|
```

But it gets only **Test1** and **Test3**

https://regex101.com/r/b2xVxH/2

Comment: In what programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regexpr

```
\|(.*?)(?=\|)
```

If your regex engine can look ahead use this one `(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\|)`

Comment: That`s what I was looking for (?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\|). Can you put some explanation about the build of this pattern?

Comment: @ErickGallani You can exclude part of selected text by `(?<=someTextBefore)` and `(?=someTextAfter)`